# Youtube Video Upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to make a browser based youtube video uploader using javascript.

I am using [sample code from here](http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html)

After authentication when I upload video, POST request to youtube server never ends and video is not uploaded.

This is happening in the [sample provided by google](http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html) too.

Here is the function that i am using to upload video:

```
$('#upload').click(function(){
    $('#upload').attr('disabled', true);

    var title = escapeXmlEntities($('#title').val());
    var description = escapeXmlEntities($('#description').val());
    var category = escapeXmlEntities($('#category option:selected').val());

    var xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"> <media:group> <media:title type="plain">' + title + '</media:title> <media:description type="plain">' + description + '</media:description> <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">' + category + '</media:category> </media:group> </entry>';
    showMsg("Submitting metadata of video to get upload token.");
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'xml',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken',
        contentType: 'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8',
        processData: false,
        headers: generateYouTubeApiHeaders(),
        data: xmlBody,
        success: function(responseXml) {
            var xml = $(responseXml);
            var nextUrl = window.location.href;
            var submissionUrl = xml.find('url').text() + '?nexturl=' + encodeURIComponent(nextUrl);
            var token = xml.find('token').text();

            showMsg("Uploading Video...");
            $('#form_upload').attr('action', submissionUrl);
            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'token',
                value: token
            }).appendTo('#form_upload');
            $('#form_upload').submit();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR) {
            showMsg('Metadata submission failed: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
            $('#upload').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#upload').val('Upload');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the firebug screenshot of the last POST request made to youtube server that is never ending.

[image: error-image]

Moreover I want to get the progress of the video upload and show it using javascript but I don't know how to achieve it I googled and found many methods but nothing was successful for me.

Comment: did  you tried using ***YouTube Data API v3.*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now support for resumable uploads using CORS in the YouTube Data API v3.

A rough, but working, example at https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html (source files at https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git%2Fyt-upload-javascript) that shows the upload flow, using the Google+ sign-in button to handle OAuth 2 (you can use the normal OAuth 2 browser client flow if you'd prefer) and with a progress indicator. It also shows how you could poll for video processing status following an upload and embed the resulting video on a page once it's been processed.

Comment: This requires the access token used to be visible in the browser. Is there a way to get an upload token like v2's GetUploadToken method?  So that users could upload videos to an account without exposing the account's access token?

Comment: @JeremyHaile did you get safely solution about it?

Comment: https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html not found, ***404 error***

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/youtube-api-samples/source#git%2Fyt-upload-javascript is ***deprecated***