# What are the client side javascript Youtube V3 API key names for gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert()?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

So I'm trying to make this Youtube V3 api method work: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

The code I have (based on my guesses from the Java and Python examples are):

```
gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
autoLevels: true,
stabilize: true,
part: 'snippet,status,fileDetails',
body: {
    snippet: {
        title: 'bla',
        description: 'bla bla bla',
        categoryId: 22,
        tags: ['bla', 'blabla']
    },
    status: {
        embeddable: true,
        publicStatsViewable: true,
        privacyStatus: 'unlisted',//this shoult make it public, but not listed in youtube search/browse
    }       
},
media_body: 'WHAT GOES HERE? AND IS media_body CORRECT?' }).execute(function(response) { });
```

So my main question is the 'media_body' key correct? What else could it be? And is the value a path to a local file? Can you even upload client side--maybe thats why they have no example for this. How does everything else look?

Comment: My answer on this thread should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19732032/1973552

Comment: why do you have to manually use ajax rather than methods like this: gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert() ??

Comment: insert method is just for adding the metadata, then you need a protocol to transfer the file itself. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol