# Uploading videos to Youtube via API, getting mediaBodyRequired error

Tags: javascript, video, youtube-javascript-api

I'm new to youtube API and want to upload videos, but i don't know how to use the `insert`,

```
fileStream = r.result;
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
        part: 'snippet, status',
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                title: 'my video',
                description: 'Description',
                categoryId: "22"
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: "private"
            }
        }
    }, fileStream);
    console.log("after request")
    request.execute(function(response) {
        var result = response.result;
        console.log(response);
        if (result) {
            console.log("execute completed");
        }
    });
}
```

but it gives an error:

```
domain: "youtube.video"
location: "body"
locationType: "other"
message: "Bad Request"
reason: "mediaBodyRequired"
```

i read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource), but didn't find witch property represent the body of the video.
anyone know how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The most workable approach is probably to implement the resumable upload protocol in Javascript using AJAX, and not the Google client libraries. Resumable upload protocol means that you first submit a request with the JSON metadata and a special parameter, and the response's `Location` header gives you a secondary, temporary URL to upload your file content to.

- Resumable upload protocol is recommended in the documentation, and the other code samples in the docs (there isn't one there for JS) use it.
- I got a non-RUP version with the API "working" but none of the uploads would process.
- I attempted to implement RUP using the Google client libraries, and at the first step the response object was `undefined` even though the underlying HTTP request/response were correct.
- There is sample code here that implements RUP using jQuery AJAX calls: https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html
- The API documentation does not really say how you should do inserts in Javascript specifically, as far as I can tell.

References:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

[Youtube Video Upload using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725673/youtube-video-upload-using-javascript/19732032#19732032)